# How to send PrtScr as Global Send Keys in Blue Prism?

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I need to take the Error Screen Shot in Blue Prism V5. Is there anyway to do it?
Is it Possible to press PrtScr using Global Send Keys and Save the image in Word Document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a Navigate stage with Global Sendkey and text "^%{PRTSC}". Then Action stage to open Word instance (Word VBO), then another Action stage and use paste or paste from clipboard (Word VBO). Then another Word VBO to Save or Save As.

Comment: The `^%` in the text are redundant. `{PRTSC}` is enough.